# unable to create sandbox even after installing flatpak

Tags: installation, sandbox, gnome, flatpak

After cloning pitivi as mentioned [here](http://developer.pitivi.org/HACKING.html?gi-language=undefined#setting-up-the-advanced-development-environment), I installed flatpak. Now running the command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

I get this message:

```
gnome-software-plugin-flatpak is already the newest version (3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.12).
```

and running the following command:

```
cd pitivi-dev/pitivi && source bin/pitivi-env
```

I get this message:

```
You need to install flatpak-builder >= 0.10.0 to be able to use the '/home/snpd/github/pitivi-dev/pitivi/build/flatpak/pitivi-flatpak' script.

You can find some information about how to install it for your distribution at:
    * http://flatpak.org/
```

I do not know what is wrong here, any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate `flatpak-builder` package you need to install.